# Java Tic Tac Toe Networking

Tags: java

Okay so, I'm trying to make a tic tac toe that has a network option. I've wrote this code but I'm having a little problem.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{       
    JButton temp=(JButton)e.getSource();
    //temp.setText("X");
    if(turn%2==0)
    {
        temp.setText("X");
        temp.setIcon(gui.imgX);
        temp.setDisabledIcon(gui.imgX);
        gui.repaint();
        gui.revalidate();
        turn++;
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<gui.buttons.length;i++)
                if(temp==gui.buttons[i])
                    out.write(i);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(turn%2==1)
    {
            try {
            System.out.println(turn);
            gui.buttons[in.read()].setText("O");
            gui.revalidate();
            System.out.println(turn);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        turn++;
    }       
}
```

Okay so, whenever I click on a button, it runs inside the next if condition(turn%2==0), but doesn't set the button icon or text. However, it actually sets it somehow in the background, so I icon and text come visible ONLY when it finishes the whole actionPerformed and reads an int from the other pc. So basically, it displays "X" and "O" together after finishing the whole actionPerformed method. How can I fix that so it shows "X" when a button gets pressed without waiting to read from the other pc. Note that it successfully write the int in the other pc and the button text/icon get changed there without waiting the other if condition.

Comment: At present you are mixing the UI things with the logic/ controller. I think it would be helpful, if you split it. I.e. while processing the ActionEvent you are waiting for the response from the "remote player", blocking all the other UI things. I would try to move the control (whos turn it is and reading from remote station) into a background thread and then update the UI only if my turn was executed or I received the information from the remote player.

Comment: @StefanFreitag Thank you alot, you should have posted this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present you are mixing the UI things with the logic/ controller. I think it would be helpful, if you split it. I.e. while processing the ActionEvent you are waiting for the response from the "remote player", blocking all the other UI things.

I would try to move the control (whos turn it is and reading from remote station) into a background thread and then update the UI only if my turn was executed or I received the information from the remote player.